# Height Map output

Tags: ros-indigo, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Regarding Velodyne lidar obstacles detection. I am using the velodyne_height_map. I was seeking to be able to detect the distance between the sensor and the obstacle and the angle at which the obstacle located. by using the publish command I was able to see the format. if you can help me to be able to understand more of the format of the output data packet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283144/height-map-output/) by [Karim Ahmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33767/karim-ahmt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `velodyne_obstacles` topic is a sensor_msgs/PointCloud2. I believe it's in the frame of reference of the input point cloud, which is normally the device frame, `velodyne`. The correct frame_id will be in the message header.

The Euclidean distance from any point in that cloud to the device, is the square root of the sum of squares of its x, y, and z coordinates.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2018-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karim Ahmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33767/karim-ahmt/) on 2018-02-21**:
thank you for your answer, but how could I know from the published topic which ones are the x ,y,and z coordinates.
as the single data packet is 32 digit no letters .

thank you.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-02-21**:
PointCloud2 is a complex message containing multiple data fields for each point. They "always" include x, y, and z, but may include other data. See: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview

**Comment by [Karim Ahmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33767/karim-ahmt/) on 2018-02-23**:
thank you very much, appreciate your support

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-02-23**:
If this answers your question, please click the check mark above.